# NUXT useFetch Call Failed

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

When i run this code in NUXT environment:

```js
 const response = await useFetch('https://seasee-headless.local/wp-json/wc/v3/products', {
    params: {
        consumer_secret: 'cs_471cbb0635a300909b2b13ebd52d2550fc0c857e',
        consumer_key: 'ck_ce1d0a5d3bf46ecbd46fdd18ba5f3fee41c094b4'
    },
});
```

It gives following result:

```json
{ "data": null, "pending": false, "error": "Error: [GET] \"https://seasee-headless.local/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_secret=cs_471cbb0635a300909b2b13ebd52d2550fc0c857e&consumer_key=ck_ce1d0a5d3bf46ecbd46fdd18ba5f3fee41c094b4\": <no response> fetch failed", "status": "error" }
```

When i add `ssr:false` to nuxt-config file , then it has been resolved. I'm confused with that.

Comment: The issue is probably not coming from the place you're showing in your question. There is no reason that this request would fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to Post it but it consider that as th Get methode.
It is better to choose the methode in your Usefetch command so:

```
const response = await useFetch('https://Your address',{
 method: "POST",
 body: {
  params: {
        consumer_secret: 'cs_471cbb0635a300909b2b13ebd52d2550fc0c857e',
        consumer_key: 'ck_ce1d0a5d3bf46ecbd46fdd18ba5f3fee41c094b4'
    },


    or your params directly

        consumer_secret: 'cs_471cbb0635a300909b2b13ebd52d2550fc0c857e',
        consumer_key: 'ck_ce1d0a5d3bf46ecbd46fdd18ba5f3fee41c094b4'

 },
    
});

for Get methode just add you options directly after your url. like this:


const response = await useFetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains', {
  query: { param1, param2: 'value2' }
})


});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you using? I was experiencing similar problems, and switching to a "newer" node version solved everything.